# Multi select-option in form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a problem. I need to have a select-option repeated on one or more lines. Something like this:

[image]

for the input field I specified

```
   <td class="col-md-12"><input  name="featureValue[]" value=""></td>
   <td class="col-md-12"><input  name="featureValue[]" value=""></td>
   <td class="col-md-12"><input  name="featureValue[]" value=""></td>
   <td class="col-md-12"><input  name="featureValue[]" value=""></td>
```

for select the option I used

```
   <select name="listFeature[]" id="listFeature_1">
   <option value="1" id="listFeature-0">Material Case </option>
   <option value="2" id="listFeature-1">Thickness Case </option>
   <option value="3" id="listFeature-2">Color Case</option>
   <option value="4" id="featureList-4">Weight</option>
   <option value="6" id="featureList-6">Models</option>
   <option value="7" id="listFeature-7">Type Movement</option>
   </select>
   <select name="listFeature[]" id="listFeature_2" >
   <option value="1" id="listFeature-0">Material Case </option>
   <option value="2" id="listFeature-1">Thickness Case </option>
   <option value="3" id="listFeature-2">Color Case</option>
   <option value="4" id="featureList-4">Weight</option>
   <option value="6" id="featureList-6">Models</option>
   <option value="7" id="listFeature-7">Type Movement</option>
   </select>
   <select name="listFeature[]" id="listFeature_3" >
   <option value="1" id="listFeature-0">Material Case </option>
   <option value="2" id="listFeature-1">Thickness Case </option>
   <option value="3" id="listFeature-2">Color Case</option>
   <option value="4" id="featureList-4">Weight</option>
   <option value="6" id="featureList-6">Models</option>
   <option value="7" id="listFeature-7">Type Movement</option>
   </select>
   <select name="listFeature[]" id="listFeature_4" >
   <option value="1" id="listFeature-0">Material Case </option>
   <option value="2" id="listFeature-1">Thickness Case </option>
   <option value="3" id="listFeature-2">Color Case</option>
   <option value="4" id="featureList-4">Weight</option>
   <option value="6" id="featureList-6">Models</option>
   <option value="7" id="listFeature-7">Type Movement</option>
   </select>
```

I need to process the couple select-option and value input. 
I have in $_POST["featureValue"] which contains an array with these values

```
$_POST["featureValue"][0]="Auto mechanic"
$_POST["featureValue"][1]="Steel"
$_POST["featureValue"][2]="Sport"
$_POST["featureValue"][3]=""
```

But $_Post["listFeature"] contains only last value

```
$_POST["listFeature"][0]= 2
```

which is associated with the value

```
$_POST["featureValue"][3]=""
```

I need

```
$_POST["listFeature"][0]= 7
$_POST["listFeature"][1]= 0
$_POST["listFeature"][2]= 6
$_POST["listFeature"][3]= 2
```

It seems that for the select-option does not work passing arrays
Can someone help me?

(translated with google translator)

Comment: You need to use `multiple` attribute for `select` tag, to allow choose multiple values from one select tag: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

Comment: @TaronSaribekyan - that's not what they're trying to do though. Look at the screenshot.

Comment: I can't actually see any reason why this wouldn't work...

Comment: I've just checked it, and everything works as you need to

Comment: Is very strange. This is the response in my php

Comment: array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "Classico"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "5.00 mm"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "Acciaio"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "6"
}

Comment: Undefined offset: 1 in <b>D:\www\puntorologio.it\myModule\controller\ctrlProduct.php
</b> on line <b>477</b><br />

Comment: second array array(1){[0]=>"6"} It does not contain 4 elements

Comment: @Taron: I tried it with multiple options but the result does not change

Comment: I verified that the isolated code works.
The problem seems to stem from the fact that I add rows in the select-option dynamically with ajax by pressing the button add feature.
When you press the button you are dynamically added a new list and a new input field. Amche if in the end the product code is exactly the one shown.

Comment: Excuse me ... The problem is due to the fact that the enabled property is false ...
Unfortunately for me would not make editable a choice already made.
How could I do?

Answer (score 0):

I verified that the code is ok. The problem is that the previous select-option will be disabled when you create a new row with the button add feature. This means that you do not pass the values of select-option disabled.
To solve the problem I disabled all the internal options of a select option keeping active only the option selected.
I then modified the code

List = document.getElementById ("listFeature _" + id);
List.setAttribute ('disabled', 'disabled');

var option =document.getElementById("listFeature").getElementsByTagName("option");
    for (var i = 0; i < op.length; i++) {
      (option [i].selected)? option [i].disabled = false : option[i].disabled = true ;
    }

Now it seems to work as my desire